# Error in magento admin reports section

Tags: magento

Hi guys i am working on a magento commerce site and got a bug in magento admin panel under reports section what actually it is that when i tries to export any report such as Shopping cart items or customer review in either CSV or xml format it gives me a file to download but with wrong extension type such as if i am downloading report as in csv format it gives me a file like

tag_customer_detail.csv-, attachment

the part (-, attachment) giving the downloaded file not to open in any editor ...
any one has address this issue before in the past or has some solution to this problem are mostly welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the content of method `exportCustomerDetailCsvAction` in file `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php`

and check what is the value assigned to `$fileName` there (You may find `-,` appended over there, but it's a wild guess).

Do you have any extension which rewrites this functionality?

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh for pointing me the source files of the error.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through the internet i found that Google Chrome has some kind of issue with 
Content-Disposition header parameter, it needs a semicolon after the file name so guys if any one has got this error with their magento 1.6.2 v please edit your code.

1) Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php
2) find a protected function _prepareDownloadResponse()
3) and change the line
->setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'"')

TO

->setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'";')

Happy coding :)